# VirtualHost on XAMPP

Tags: xampp, apache

I'm using XAMPP lite on Windows 7, but instead of `http://localhost` I'd like to have `http://mycustomname` mapped to a directory `myfolder` in root/htdocs.

What should I change in httpd.conf?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mycustomname
    ServerAlias mycustomname
    DocumentRoot "c:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now edit c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and add a new line:

```
127.0.0.1        mycustomname
```

Which will cause Windows to resolve your custom name to 127.0.0.1. Restart Apache and you can access your site.

Comment: The URL to access your site in this example would be:  http:// mycustomname  You can also use a dotted name such as yoursite.localhost in place of mycustomname.