# multiple application access in one codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter framwork . I have two applications in one Code Igniter project.

```
-multipleApp 
    - application
       - one
           -- controller
           -- model
           -- view
           -- helper
       - Two
           -- controller
           -- model
           -- view
           -- helper
       - index_two.php
     - index.php
```

Now I am able access my web application one ie. localhost/welcome/test

now my question is how can i access both applications in localhost ??

**index.php**: application folder looks like this

```
$application_folder = 'application/one';
```

**index_two.php**:

```
$application_folder = 'application/two';
```

Is this correct way for access two application in one codeigniter folder?

Here's my current **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|css|js|template|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /multipleApp/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You need to access your `index_two.php` file to use the 2nd application.  You'll need to make rules in `.htaccess` to redirect users there.  What URLs do you want to point to the 2nd app?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: i need to access localhost/two/welcome/test. anything need to add in .htaccess file ??

Comment: Can you post your current `.htaccess`?  You'll need to add a rule for `/two` just like you have for your 1st app.

Comment: @rocket hazmat:RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|css|js|template|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /multipleApp/index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

One way to set this out is to have two folders each with the proper index.php file like so:

```
-multipleApp 
    - application
       - one
           -- controller
           -- model
           -- view
           -- helper
       - Two
           -- controller
           -- model
           -- view
           -- helper
     - index.php
-app2_index_folder
    - index_two.php
```

So that you can access both apps through `localhost/multipleApp/` and `localhost/app2_index_folder/`

Another option is to setup a VirtualHost and that way you can access: `app1.localhost` and `app2.localhost`

but, having both URLs sharing the same core files.

See this link [Setup VirtualHost on Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947796/virtualhost-on-xampp) or [Create VirtualHost on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575987/how-to-create-virtualhost-in-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: i am getting like this.. Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index_two.php